# What is the meaning of these phrases?

Tags: expressions

[image]

I want to know the meaning of these phrases or expressions:

1. Down to the wood.
2. Feel a fuzz
3. Feel rough.

I have also provided a picture of the source.

Comment: Next time try looking up expressions you don't recognize in a dictionary before asking about them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[down to the wood](http://lisaguenther.com/down-to-the-wood/)** means shaving your head with a razor, rather than using clippers, so that there is no hair at all sticking out of the skin.

**[fuzz](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fuzz)** means a covering of short thin soft hairs

**[rough](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rough)** means it does not feel smooth when you touch it: